# Incorrect format of email address from CurrentUser.Address in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to get the current user's Outlook email address with

```
 Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address;
```

The value this displays is somewhat like this:

> "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (xxxxxxxxx)/cn=Recipients/cn=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-[the beginning of my email address is here]"

The first problem is that the email address is cut off. I at first thought that this is a breakpoint issue, but after modifying the string I found it's just cut off by default. The second is that I only want the email address value without all the data before. I could edit out the string but I'm looking for the proper way of getting the value.

This works when the user logs in via Exchange.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
```

I'm looking for the equivalent for users not logged in via Exchange.

I found [Email Address of the Current User](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2d9bf23-e27f-4f30-9199-42833d6919a4/email-address-of-the-current-user?forum=vsto) but it is an old thread and the solutions all seem pretty hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `AddressEntry.Type` property. If it is "EX", use `GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. Otherwise just read the `Address` property.

Comment: That's the problem, when I read Address I get this large string that is cut off.

Comment: For which address type? Something other than "EX"?

Comment: Yes, for all other address types. Not all logged in accounts are of type EX.

Comment: I think you missed my point (see above) you need to check AddressEntry.Type property. If it is "EX", then use GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress. Otherwise just read the AddreessEntry.Address property.

Comment: Oh okay apparently the email I was checking it on was of type EX... It works now.